# "command not found" when doing “sudo easy install pip”​

Tags: python, pip

I want to learn Python. Based on my tutorial, I understand I need to install "pip", with the following line in terminal :

```
sudo easy install pip
```

But I get `command not found`

Looking quickly online, I understand it may have to do with my `"$PATH"`?

I don't know what it means, for for info my $PATH seems to be:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

What would I need to change (and how) to be able to install pip ?

Comment: It's `easy-install`, not `easy install`. And, of course, you need to actually have it installed itself. More frequently, you'll want to install pip through your operating system's package manager.

Comment: thanks a lot. Then "sudo pip install requests" gives me that : The directory '/Users/gui/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
The directory '/Users/gui/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and ow...

Answer (score 1):

Is it typo? Command should be `sudo easy_install pip`

Comment: ha, it seems it was indeed. Thank you very much! But now the next command is “sudo pip install requests”. Is there a typo as well?​ Because I get the following :                                                                                             The directory '/Users/gui/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python i